# Why doesn't Minitest's assert_raises work as expected in this case?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm trying to sort out a weird behavior in Rails using the [Action Controller bug report template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/bug_report_templates/action_controller_gem.rb).

For the record, this is the controller in the template:

```
class TestController < ActionController::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def index
    render text: 'Home'
  end
end
```

I've added a route to a missing action:

```
routes.draw do
  get '/' => 'test#index'
  get '/missing' => 'test#missing'
end
```

and I'm trying to assert that `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` is raised when following that route:

```
class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def test_missing
    assert_raises(AbstractController::ActionNotFound) { get '/missing' }
  end

  private
    def app
      Rails.application
    end
end
```

Expected behavior: green test.

Actual behavior:

```
# Running tests:

D, [2014-04-24T09:17:41.948985 #4497] DEBUG -- :
D, [2014-04-24T09:17:41.949029 #4497] DEBUG -- :
I, [2014-04-24T09:17:41.949094 #4497]  INFO -- : Started GET "/missing" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-24 09:17:41 +0200
F, [2014-04-24T09:17:41.951337 #4497] FATAL -- :
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'missing' could not be found for TestController):
[stacktrace]

  1) Failure:
BugTest#test_missing [action_controller_gem.rb:45]:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound expected but nothing was raised.
```

So, basically, **the exception is raised but Minitest is claiming nothing was raised.** I am stumped here.

Why can't Minitest assert that `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` is raised? I've looked into `Rack::Test::Methods` to rule out that `get` works with threads or something but couldn't find anything.

I've also looked at the [implementation of `assert_raises`](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_raises) -- nothing obvious.

**Why doesn't `assert_raises(AbstractController::ActionNotFound) { get '/missing' }` pass?**

(Never mind the fact that this is already tested in Rails. I'm trying to get past this for the real deal.)

Comment: please show `TestController`. and full `BugTest` class

Comment: Added it for clarity. I didn't modify the template (linked in first sentence) for `TestController` and just added `test_missing` to `BugTest`.

Comment: you `TestController` should inherited from `ApplicationController`. or you have full [app](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/bug_report_templates/action_controller_gem.rb) in example ?

Comment: I took the AC template we both referenced by now, added a route and added a test method. Why should I change the super class of `TestController`?

Comment: i mean you have full listing or chunk? because i use this and this work for me.

Comment: ok i test and this not work on Rails 4.1.0. i have same errors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't a problem with `assert_raises`, that continues to work just fine. The issue you are having is that the exception you are raising within your Rails app is getting handled by your Rails app and not propagating out to your test. Calling `get '/missing'` is raising the `AbstractController::ActionNotFound` error, but then your app handles the error and returns an appropriate response (404 or 500) to the client (your test).

Okay, so how would you go about testing that your controller really did raise the error you are expecting? Normally you would just use an `ActionController::TestCase` test to test your controllers. But, when you call an action on a controller that doesn't in `ActionController::TestCase` you get a different error. So the following:

```
require "test_helper"

class TestControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def test_missing
    assert_raises AbstractController::ActionNotFound do
      get :missing
    end
  end
end
```

Produces the following output:

```
  1) Failure:
TestControllerTest#test_missing [test/controllers/test_controller_test.rb:6]:
[AbstractController::ActionNotFound] exception expected, not
Class: <ActionController::UrlGenerationError>
Message: <"No route matches {:action=>\"missing\", :controller=>\"test\"}">
---Backtrace---
test/controllers/test_controller_test.rb:7:in `block in test_missing'
test/controllers/test_controller_test.rb:6:in `test_missing'
---------------
```

The reason is because `ActionController::TestCase` is aware of the routes and won't allow calling an action that is not in the routes. But that is exactly what you are trying to test. And, I assume why you aren't using `ActionController::TestCase`.

At this point I wonder if you aren't testing something you shouldn't. Perhaps you should allow Rails to do its job and trust that it behaves correctly. But hey, we've come this far, why not just go all the way and test what Rails tests anyway. Instead of making the call through the full Rails app, let's try calling the `TestController` directly. If we create a new instance of the controller we can ask it to handle an action even if that action is not defined on the controller. But to do this we will have to dive deep into how ActionController works and make use of the [`AbstractController#process`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-i-process) method:

```
require "test_helper"

class TestControllerTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_missing
    assert_raises AbstractController::ActionNotFound do
      TestController.new.process :missing
    end
  end
end
```

Now we are asking the controller to process an action that doesn't exist and testing that the controller behaves as expected. Yay?

Comment: "At this point I wonder if you aren't testing something you shouldn't. Perhaps you should allow Rails to do its job and trust that it behaves correctly." – OP here. I'm yak-shaving, and this is just the first problem I encountered. As you can see, the last part of my question is "Never mind the fact that this is already tested in Rails. I'm trying to get past this for the real deal." Thanks for the longish explanation, it helps a lot!